# Unlock Jenkins Lockable Resources

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any way to unlock jenkins lockable resources through the groovy console? We think we rebooted our instance while a lock was held and now jobs are all stuck thinking the lock is held.

Comment: Is it only one lock? In that case you should be able to unlock the lock using the ui.

Comment: Yea I'm embarrassed to say I missed it in the ui. That worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

Additional info:
The buttons at the page https://jenkins-url/jenkins/lockable-resources/ are only shown when the user has permissions to reserve and/or unlock lockable resources manually. These permissions are activated through at Jenkins page: Jenkins->Administration->Configure Global Security.